# Way to enter the BIOS of linux server

Tags: centos7, bios, intel, intel-vt-x

I have a Centos 7.9 VPS up and running. I wanted to enter into BIOS, but I wonder if there is any specific key to enter into it.

I wanted to enable the vt-d inside the BIOS. My server has Intel CPU which has vt-d support.

Thanks.

Comment: such questions should be addressed to your VPS provider

Comment: You need to ask your VPS provider if they support nested virtualisation. I think they don't support it in general, so that would leave renting a dedicated server as an option.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the platform you are using.

Typically on a hypervisor environment (local or in the Cloud) you should be able to access the "console" of the virtual server. A virtualised BIOS is presented here to make any necessary BIOS changes specific to that virtual machine.

However, if you are running your local server (or Desktop)  with a hypervisor, you should be able to hit the BIOS Setup key (e.g. F2) before the operating system boots. From here you will be able to toggle Intel VT-d settings etc. Obviously be very careful when making changes to the BIOS on a physical machine.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your second point.